# how to use paypal subscription form for multiple subscriptions?

Tags: php, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to use paypal subscription form for multiple product, but its not working.

Here is my form which i used.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="archirayan9@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Baseball Hat Monthly - test2 " />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="asd">

<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

This form is for 1 product subscription. I want to make it for multiple products with different `item_id`.

I cant found any thing that help me to setup multiple product subscription using this form.

Anyone have solution how to do?

Comment: use diifferent item_name with diffrent item_number please refrer https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: ok but how can i set different subscription amount for different product?